# How to take a screenshot of an entire scrolling activity?

Tags: screenshots, samsung-galaxy-y

I have a Samsung Galaxy Y, and I have an application that has a scrollable activity. I wanted to take a screenshot but the "Home button - Power button" combination only captures the contents that are visible on the screen. What I wanted is to capture the full activity of the app including the unscrolled parts... I hope I explained it well ...

Comment: That cannot be done am afraid - ICS only takes the snapshot of the activity regardless if there's more views hidden in the scrollable area... only thing you can do is to scroll down a bit more, snapshot it, scroll down a bit more snapshot it.

Comment: Check my answer below, now it is possible from PC :-)

Comment: You could also take a screen shot every time you scroll down then edit them together into one big pic

Comment: Some others apps suggested as a workaround: [Here's why you can't take scrolling screenshots on Android 11](https://www.androidauthority.com/android-11-scrolling-screenshots-1085351/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check the scrollscreenshot tool: https://github.com/PGSSoft/scrollscreenshot

It makes multiple screenshots and simulates drag events to scroll content between each screenshot, then join all images into one.

[image: example]

Disclaimer: I'm author of this tool, it was published by [my employer](http://www.pgs-soft.com). Feature requests are welcome.

Comment: Linked my account just to upvote this. Just wish it was easier getting the inertia parameter right.

Comment: Awesome. Do you have an app ?. So I can do it with just my phone.

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales - it would require rooted phone and deep trust such app won't harm you. Or at least gone berserk and reset your phone because of some unfortunate event sequence.

Answer (score 1):

As was said - this cannot be done. I am just putting this in an answer form...

The reason being is that screenshots work by converting what is on the screen to an image - what is on the screen is pulled directly from the hardware.

Obviously, the screen doesn't know what is *going* to be displayed, a bit like we don't know exactly what is going to happen tomorrow (unless you're psychic, but we will ignore that for this analogy).

As such, there is no way to do this.

What you *could* do however, is to take many screenshots, scrolling down a bit, and then use a graphics package to stick the two screenshots together - may not look nice, but it will have to do I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

As said, a simple screenshot cannot do this for the mentioned reasons. What you could, however, do, is a *ScreenCast* -- which is easiest described as a video recording of your activities. [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) is one of the apps offering this for free (experimental, and root required). [Searching the playstore for "screencast"](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=screencast&c=apps) will show you additional candidates. However, root will be required to operate them.

Aside from that, and not requiring root, is to make a series of screenshots, as suggested by t0mm13b already, and then using an image editor to connect them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take a scrolling screenshot of any webpage in android or iPhone you need to install an app for this.

Android Users can install **Stitch & Share app** in your android device from play store and follow the simple steps provided in demo.

iOS users can install **Trytailor app** or **Stitch It app**  from app store. Once you download this app check the video and follow the steps. Also don’t forget to give access to your photos.

Source: [How to Take Scrolling Screenshots on Android and iPhone](http://www.indabaa.com/how-to-take-scrolling-screenshots-on-android-iphone/)

**Disclosure**: I'm the author of the linked article.