# Extract some messages from WhatsApp in a "long screenshot"

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, screenshots

I need to extract some messages from WhatsApp in a way of a long screenshot. A long screenshot means that amount of messages is bigger than the physical screenshot of the device. I often see such screenshots posted on Reddit.

Is there such an application that can do it for me or do I need to do it manually?

Comment: Possible dupe: [How to take a screenshot of an entire scrolling activity?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35012/44325)

Comment: You could try to use a web browser (on the phone or a PC) and then use WhatsApp Web to look at the conversation. A lot of web browsers contain the functionality to save the shown web page as xxl screenshot e.g. as image or pdf file.